# \AtEndOfEveryFile is executed in \begin{itemize}

Tags: bugs, hooks, filehook

I was quite surprised that the `\AtEndOfEveryFile` hook defined by the [filehook package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/filehook/filehook.pdf) is executed in `\begin{itemize}`.

Is this behaviour intended?
If not, how and where do I file a bug report?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filehook}

\AtEndOfEveryFile{(eof)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug. When you use `itemize` LaTeX has to load a font file that contains the `\textbullet` symbol (`texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd`), so the hook is applied right before the symbol is typeset. You get the same output if you use `\textbullet` outside `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filehook}
\AtEndOfEveryFile{(eof)}
\begin{document}
\textbullet
\end{document}
```

Comment: indeed, it is not related to `\begin{itemize}`. If I replace the content with `\item[-] a` eof is not printed. Thank you.